# sql query to get a list of items exclusive to one table

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select id,name from tab1;
select id,name from tab2;
```

I want the list of all id,name that is in tab2 but not in tab1.

what should be my query?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: what should be the format to try not in for 2 columns?

Answer (score 2):

Should be as simple as

```
select id,name from tab2
minus
select id,name from tab1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The more convenient way is `minus` (or `except` in other DBMSes). But if you need to test inclusion of two columns into some list (handwritten or generated by subquery) you need to put a tuple in test condition:

```
select *
from tab1
where (id, name) not in (
  select f.id, f.name
  from tab2 f
)
```

But remember, that it has a [trap](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=not-in-operator-with-null-data) related to`null`: if a single column of list is `null` then entire condition will be not `true`, so will not return the data.